# write logs to oldest file in directory

Tags: java, file, logging, file-io, java.util.logging

I want to do some tweaks to my logging for my application...
I would like some help to enhance what I have below in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Handler h = new FileHandler("../logs/MyLogFile_"
                    + sdf.format(date) + ".log", true);
            h.setFormatter(new SingleLineFormatter());
            h.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            logger.addHandler(h);
        }

        //...   
}
```

It creates a log file with date stamp everytime I run the application. But I want to achieve something like this in my Unix Directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 r787848 dev  45271 Feb  4  11:31 MyLogFile.log.06
-rw-r--r-- 1 r787848 dev  45308 Feb  5  11:36 MyLogFile.log.05
-rw-r--r-- 1 r787848 dev  44336 Feb  6  06:50 MyLogFile.log.04
-rw-r--r-- 1 r787848 dev  44379 Feb  7  08:41 MyLogFile.log.03
-rw-r--r-- 1 r787848 dev  44409 Feb  10 08:45 MyLogFile.log.02
-rw-r--r-- 1 r787848 dev  44446 Feb  11 12:36 MyLogFile.log.01
```

I want to define a set of lets say 6 log files to capture logging of daily run of the application. When it comes to logging, I want the application to write to the log file that is oldest, so in the above instance, running the application on `Feb 12 08:45` should clear `MyLogFile.log.06` and write fresh for `feb 12`.

How can this be achieved with `java.util.logging` on top of what I have. Unfortunately, I am not able to configure `log4j` properties and want to use `java.util.logging` only.

Comment: If it always writes to the file that is oldest, won't ever only one file be created? Or you mean write to oldest only after having created 6 files?

Answer (score 0):

The only close approximation is to do the following:

```
Handler h = new FileHandler("../logs/MyLogFile_"
                + sdf.format(date) + ".log", Integer.MAX_VALUE, 6, false);
```

See: [JDK-6350749](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6350749) - Enhance FileHandler to have Daily Log Rotation capabilities.